# Prevent item stacking using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a project. For this project, I would like to prevent items from stacking. Is there a way to do this with commands?

Comment: A Bukkit/Spigot plugin would probably help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? **i was asking for help**, what help? **can't stack items** what type of items? All items? Should this apply only to command blocks?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for "a command", you probably mean one. That simply isn't possible. There's no command that does this.

You could build a big command block system that either deletes items that are in stacks of 2+ or spreads them out (which would be problematic in a full inventory) or whatever. But that's a major project, not one command. And it wouldn't work that nicely.

If you just need a few types of items to be unstackable, you can just use unstackable items and, if you need to, retexture them to look like other items (and change the name in the language file). These are the unstackable items:

- all tools
- all weapons
- all player and horse armor
- shield
- all filled buckets (including fish)
- saddles
- all minecarts
- all boats
- compass
- clock
- filled maps (can't be retextured)
- potions (many different textures possible)
- written book
- enchanted books
- elytra
- all shulker boxes
- all records
- all banners and banner patterns
- rabbit stew, mushroom soup and suspicious stew

Keep in mind that the players can still use the items like normal, even if you retexture and rename them. So you would either want to give them items they can't use (like a clock) or prevent them from using the items in some other way.

Comment: I like the idea of spreading the blocks out. How could you do that?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. You would probably need a lot of commands, create a lot of lag and make items in inventories constantly blink, among other side effects. It's probably not worth it. What's wrong with just using regular unstackable items?