# 1.13+ how do you get the slot NBT tag for /give?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm working on a little arena map for my friends and me and I need to give a weird invisibility totem. The person should get five and It consumes all of them at once if I stack them so I need to spread the out in the hotbar. I am using /give to give all five and am using 5 different command blocks. I am using a separate detection system for each totem but this is the command I have so far:

```
give @a[scores={assassin=1..}] minecraft:wither_skeleton_skull{slot:1b,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Invisibility Totem\",\"color\":\"gray\",\"strikethrough\":\"true\"}"}} 1
```

It's the part at the beginning of the NBT tags that says: *slot:1b*, the command works perfectly otherwise. Anyone know what I should use there or if they still have this in the game as of 1.13?

Comment: "still" in 1.13? That never worked. And why don't you just use an unstackable item?

Comment: I'll just guess that you mean the same as in this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324904/prevent-item-stacking-using-commands

Comment: I mean you could name them all slightly differently with adding spaces at the beginning or end or something. You could also maybe use different colors so they don't stack, and https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/bdvsxh/my_next_datapack_3x3_crafting_in_the_players/#thing_t1_el1wy95 might be of interest to you, specifically how he blocks off certain slots. Otherwise, I'd say use unstackable items, retextured to match your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the replaceitem command will suit you, since the give command gives out an item as if the player picks it up.

```
/replaceitem entity @a[scores={assassin=1..}] inventory.0 minecraft:wither_skeleton_skull{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Invisibility Totem\",\"color\":\"gray\",\"strikethrough\":\"true\"}"}} 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way the `/give` command works is by throwing you the item specified. If it's a non-stackable item, you'll pick it up as if it were a sword, but if it's a stackable item, you'll pick it up as if it were something like planks. In order to prevent that from happening is by using the `/replaceitem` command. Like so:

```
/replaceitem entity @a[scores={assassin=1..}] container.4 minecraft:wither_skeleton_skull{slot:1b,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Invisibility Totem\",\"color\":\"gray\",\"strikethrough\":\"true\"}"}} 1
```

You'll still need to use 5 command blocks as the slot `container.4` will change to `container.5`, `container.6` and so on.
Hope this helps!